# Magento: paginate filtered product collection

Tags: php, magento

i want to filter and paginate a product collection. everything is fine - except pagination. im just getting the whole collection back, instead of 3 items for the first page.

```
    //fetch all visible products
    $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    //set wanted fields (nescessary for filter)
    $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('description');
    $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
    $product_collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));

    //filter by name or description
    $product_collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
          array('attribute'=>'name','like'=>$sTerm),
          array('attribute'=>'description','like'=>$sTerm)
    ));

    //filter for max price
    foreach ($product_collection as $key => $item) {
        if($item->getPrice() >= $priceTo){
             $product_collection->removeItemByKey($key);
        }
    }

    //pagination (THIS DOESNT WORK!)
    $product_collection->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);

    //TEST OUTPUT
    foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
          echo $product->getName().'<br />';
    }
```

thanks for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Ben! You gave me the right hint. Now it does work! Basically I'm creating another collection and filter this one by the ids of the already filtered items. Afterwards its easy to add pagination to that new collection. That's the working code:

```
    //fetch all visible products
    $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    //set wanted fields (nescessary for filter)
    $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('description');
    $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
    $product_collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));

    //filter by name or description
    $product_collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
          array('attribute'=>'name','like'=>$sTerm),
          array('attribute'=>'description','like'=>$sTerm)
    ));

    //filter for max price
    foreach ($product_collection as $key => $item) {
        if($item->getPrice() >= $priceTo){
             $product_collection->removeItemByKey($key);
        }
    }

    //build id array out of filtered items (NEW!)
    foreach($product_collection as $item){
        $arrProductIds[]=$item->getId();
    }

    //recreate collection out of product ids (NEW)
    $product_filtered_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $product_filtered_collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$arrProductIds));


    //add pagination (on new collection) (NEW)
    $product_filtered_collection->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);


    //TEST OUTPUT
    foreach ($product_filtered_collection as $product) {
          echo $product->getName().'<br />';
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

You are so close! Try moving that `$product_collection->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);` line *before* the first `foreach()` iteration over the collection.

Magento collections are lazy-loaded. Until you directly `load()` them (or implicitly load them via a call to `count()` or `foreach()`) you can modify the collection properties which affect the underlying query (**EDIT**: see note below). Once the collection has been loaded explicitly or implicitly though you will only get the members of the `_items` property that have been set.

FYI you can call `clear()` to leave the original query-affecting properties (filters, sorters, limits, joins, etc) in place and then add further properties.

HTH

**EDIT**: Actually, adjusting query properties is always possible regardless of _items load state, but the effect won't be visible until the collection is regenerated.

Comment: thanks so far! I tried to regenerate the collection:
`$product_filtered_collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        foreach ($product_collection as $item){
            $product_filtered_collection->addItem($item);
        }
` ... and added pagination to this new collection

but that doesnt work either

Comment: Ugh. I just re-read your post. You are going to have two larger issues to address. In order to paginate your collection, the price filtering needs to be part of the original query to load data (which it isn't, as the `foreach()` loads the data first. Also, depending on your needs, final price logic in Magento can be affected by observers which will not run for the items in this collection. Sorry!

Comment: yeah @Ben! you pointed me into the right direction. Now it does work. I'll post the working example in about 4h (cause my credits are too low)

basically its about creating a new collection, filter it by the product ids of the items, and paginate it afterwards. Great!